# What is the right way to create a customised log to track past taks and create new tasks in Jira

Tags: logging, jira, jira-agile

I am new to Jira. I want to create a log of all the tasks performed by my team in a customized class-object type to maintain a record of past requests and also use it for present & future requests. I am not clear on what to use to create a log. Is creating a new epic to create and maintain a log a good idea or do we have any other alternate options for these kind of assignments.

My tasks has 5 attributes as mentioned in a tabular format below.

```
Task_ID  Task_Name    Description     Status    Task Owner  

T_1

T_2
```

1. Task_ID is a unique identifier to track a task
2. Status is a categorical feature with 4 categories(Created/Sent/Shipped/Delivered)
3. Rest of features are repeatable value fields

Can anyone suggest me how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can take, depending on how much you want to manipulate the data.

The simplest approach would be to create and save filters for each team member. You could then run the filters or use a dashboard to display the data.

You could also create a dedicated board that showed all tasks for the team using swimlanes for each member of the team.

For more control over the data you could export the filter as a csv and manipulate it as a spreadsheet.

Finally, to get total control over the data you could use the Jira API to extract what you need. Then use a database or data warehouse to manipulate the data how you want to.